# How can I access my MSO profile from the Android mobile application?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

Most of the time I'm not in front of my computer, so I often use the mobile application (the Android one). The problem is that every time I want to check my activity (questions, answers, etc.) on Meta Stack Overflow, I have to use the browser instead, as I didn't find any way to access it directly from the mobile application.

So, is there any way to do that without using the mobile app? Or is it a new feature that we may suggest?

**NB:** The sites on the left menu (as many suggest) redirect to the questions page, not to the profile overview.

Comment: This probably should be tagged `[feature-request]` instead of `[support]`, but I leave the decision to you.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  you are right, I will change it immediately